# Combining .csv and adding filename as column including where filename contains space

Tags: csv, cmd

Answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914959/combining-csv-and-adding-filename-as-column?newreg=289be36ba2f846bea5e7c226320265c4) works only if there are no spaces in the filename.

> for /f %a in ('dir /b *.csv') do for /f "tokens=*" %b in (%a) do echo %b,%a >> all.csv

Spaces in filename produce error: "The system cannot find the file csvfile."

How can this be modified to accommodate files that have space in their name?

e.g.

csvfile 1.csv

csvfile 2.csv

csvfile 3.csv

Comment: has nothing to do with DOS (there is no `for /f` in DOS), so I changed the tag to `cmd`

Answer (score 0):

This worked

> for /r . %a in (*.csv) do for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %b in ("%a") do
> echo %b,%~nxa >> all.csv